# how can I recommend a method in java?

Tags: java, methods

how can I recommend a method in java? example, in this image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oKca.png)

"System.out.println", there is a star in front of method "println", I don't know how to mark my customize method a star method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do so.
Why are there stars? The explanation is here:
[image]